# How can i see SQLite Database (No emulator)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

For development , sometimes we need for a faster programming , the SQLite database state of our programs . But i can only extract database if it's on emulator , not mobile .

Then my exactly question is ¿Is there a way to see the android sqlite db or a way to extract it?

If there isn't a good answer to that question . How do you manage with that programming issues when you need to know the db state of the tables?

Comment: Root your device.... or manage for nexsus 1 or for that is always better to try first in emu and check if db is correct then test on device

Comment: Sorry but using the emu is not the way i think to do it faster

Comment: Do you just need to explore the database that was created?

Comment: @A.Quiroga I have posted one answer pls have a look. That might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
adb shell
```

to get a root shell of the device, then use anything you like directly on the DB. Export it, run scripts etc etc.

You can check out this link for details:

[developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html)

Abount SQLite commands:
http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Comment: Thx for your answer , Could you give me the exactly way to extract or to manage sqlite db in order to tick you?

Comment: @A.Quiroga You're welcome. I added the neccessary links to my answer.

Comment: The sqlite3 link was moved here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3.html

Comment: @vovahost feel free to edit the answer, you will get the credit for it ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this from shell as `vbence` mentioned. Another way is to copy the database file to sd card programatically. Call this in `onStop()`:

```
File source =  new File("data/data/com.ACME/databases/" + DATABASE_NAME);
File dest =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME + ".db");

public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) {

FileChannel source = null;
FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        /* handle exception... */
    } finally {
    try {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* handle exception... */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For exploring the SQLite database you can use the addon of mozilla firefox named [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/). And after running the app pull the database to your system using file explorer and open the firefox-->Tools-->SQLite Manager. A window will come and on that there is an option to open the database, click on that and direct to the path where you have pulled your DB. Open that DB you can see the tables created and the values you have entered. Also you have the option to add, edit, delete and update the values.