# sqlite3: not found

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

I am trying to reach the sqlite database on my device using the procedure described here: [How can i see SQLite Database (No emulator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632767/how-can-i-see-sqlite-database-no-emulator)

However, I keep on getting sqlite3 not found.
I assume I am meant to be entering the commands with the hash (#) sign at the start of the line. 
I tried with it and got nothing. 
Without it I get the error message.

The sqlite3.exe file is definitely there and in the path.

Do I have to install something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-op

The second answer on this page has worked for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Some manufacturers deliver the devices without sqlite being installed on them. You can copy the sqlite program though from a emulator to your device if the device has an arm processor.

1. Start the emulator and use the `adb` command from the `platform-tools` in android-sdk

   `adb pull /system/xbin/sqlite3`
2. Mount the system partition of your device read/write after this tutorial:

   http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html
3. Use the `adb` command to copy the sqlite3 file to your device

   `adb push sqlite3 /system/xbin/`

After you reboot your device the `sqlite3` command should work.

**Edit** (copy from linked page - in the case link becomes invalid). The instructions for step 2 are:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

> "Replace /dev/block/mtdblock3 & /system with appropriate device path and mount point, as obtained from cat /proc/mounts"

Comment: Tried this but the pull command fails because it can't find the sqlite3 file. It's not in xbin. Where can I find it?

Comment: please make sure, that the physical device is **not** connected and your emulator is running when executing the adb pull!

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong. I did cat /proc/mounts and from the line "/dev/block/stl9 /system" I took the values. I then entered "mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/st19 /system". How do I now copy? I tried from within the adb shell but it won't accept he command. When I exit the shell and then enter the command it claims it is read-only.

Comment: Maybe you could copy the `sqlite3` file to the sd-card first with the push command. Afterwards you go to the `adb shell`, enter `su` and then something like: `mv /mnt/sdcard/sqlite3 /system/xbin`

Comment: Ok. So I maanaged to push to /mnt/sdcard. Now when I eneter adb shell and try "su" it doesn't recognise the command.

Comment: This only works if your phone is rooted, You can try though to mount your `/system` partition read/write but I guess you have no write permission on the /system/xbin folder without root. If you want to root your phone you will find several tutorials in google. Otherwise you can call the `sqlite3`command also directly from the sd-card. Just do (in the adb shell) `cd /mnt/sdcard`, `chmod +x sqlite3` and then you can call the program always with the absolute path `/mnt/sdcard/sqlite3`

Comment: I'd rather not root my tablet and phone if I can avoid it so I will go down the second path and go directly via the sdcard. Many thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4525/discussion-between-theblitz-and-dyonisos)

Comment: sentence: `After you reboot your device the sqlite3 command should work` is very important clue

Comment: Thanks for that, @hBrent. I tried `cat /proc/mounts` but it spit out a bunch of stuff I didn't understand. Using Luke's comment from that answer you linked did the trick, though.

Comment: Also, instead of getting sqlite from an emulator, I had Titanium Backup installed, which has it. So I just did `cp /data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/files/sqlite3 /system/xbin/` to copy it over

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to Play store --> search for `Titanium Backup` & install it
2. `adb shell`
3. `su`
4. `cp /data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/files/sqlite3 /system/xbin/`
5. `cd /system/xbin/`
6. `chmod 755 sqlite3`
7. `adbd reboot` (just in case)
8. Enjoy the result

Answer (score 0):

For those who, like me, couldn't use Sqlite3, I used a workaround for this:

```
cat srcfile> / mnt / sdcard / dstfile
```

With this you can put the files into an external .db manager.