# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data_id (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite

When I try to query the CallLog data from android phone, I got the following error. *android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT CallsStat_id, ip_prefix, numberlabel, matched_number, type, date, contactid, statNew, lookup_uri, moduletype, _id, name, normalized_number, ring_count, photo_id, formatted_number, number, geocoded_location, countryiso, data_id, numbertype, new, duration, simid, isprivate, voicemail_uri, is_read, raw_contact_id, vtcall FROM calls_restrict_view ORDER BY duration DESC.* But, the query work correctly some android phone. Here is my code.`Cursor managedCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,CallLog.Calls.DURATION + " " + sorting);`

Comment: Have you tried pulling the database base out of the device/emulator to make sure all the columns are there?

Comment: I'm just a beginner in android. So, please let me know how to pulling the database out of the device/emulator. Thank you Kristy Welsh.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Try this to pull out the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio