# How to display database table in Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, database, show

I have created a SQL Lite database table with two columns in Android Studio and I have entered some rows . I want to know how to display this table in an Android Studio Activity

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this, and a fair amount of questions have popped up on my first [google search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio). This should be helpful enough. Also, since Android studio is intellij based, check [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/accessing-android-sqlite-databases-from-intellij-idea.html) out.