# How to use DDMS within Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, ddms

I'm trying to see the contents of a database I'm using through the execution of my program via DDMS. I've looked at lot of questions on here that explain how it's done. My understanding relies on the fact that on clicking Tools--> Android--> Android Device Monitor, there is a change in perspective however nothing of the sort happens when I do the above. In fact, there seems to be no indication at all, that I selected the Android Device Monitor. Could someone please point me in the right direction of finding out what could be wrong?

Comment: Clicking on Tools--> Android--> Android Device Monitor should open a new windows for Android Device Monitor. Its a tool outside of Android Studio

Comment: Thanks @will421 ! No window opens for me. Do you have any possible idea as to how I could fix that?

Comment: Try launch it yourself with <sdk_folder>/tools/monitor.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off what @will421 said in the comments, I ran monitor.bat and the typed out monitor in the console (Both needed to be done.) and then I was prompted to enter my sdk path. What tripped me up was the fact that I had two folders labelled sdk and sdk1 so choosing the right one is important. To view the contents of the dtatabase, I just followed along with the great answer at [View contents of database file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio)