# Android - SQLite database management

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have an app developed in android studio 1.4 and I am trying to see what is my best option for data storage. I want the app to work offline, so I decided on bundling it with an SQLite database. I currently have the data in a MySql database, the problem is importing the database.

I used the emulator **adb tool under platform tools** inside the SDK ,as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studiohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio), to inject several tables of data and it worked fine. In only one table I have about **16000** records that are merely foreign-key references and a name (not too computationally intensive). When I copy and paste into the command line tool, for this table, it freezes. I think the tool cannot handle that much inserts. Hence I have a few concerns as I Intend to put the app onto the play-store.

- I can use android studio to pull out the database, use an SQLite client to try inserting the bulky table, but how do I get it back on to he emulator and by extension my phone when I package it?
- Is there a better way to manage the database? That is, when I need to
  push updates to the database (values only, no structural changes to
  tables).
- I don't want to put the db script as a recourse in the app to add to the size of the app. Beside that, persons can simply de-compile my apk and get my db script.

Can anyone with a better understanding than I, please offer some guidance or point me to a resource that will explain about **how these "in-app databases" are usually initialized and maintained?**

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all the data at your mobile app? 
Is it possible that you only need part of the data depending on the user of the application?

When I came across the same issue, I served the data to the mobile application via a REST API as JSON. The mobile aplpication user may trigger the call to the API or it might run as a service.

I encountered memory issues when I tried to parse the huge JSON response. Use `com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader` and do not load the whole string at once.

Make sure you that this process is not executed on the UI thread.