# i am getting error while i am adding data to my cart using sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

here is my code for i m displaying listview in that listview i am taking one button when i am click on that button that perticular data will be added into cart but it does not display item into cart..

```
    public class All_Item_Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    // Declare Variables
    SQLiteDatabase sqLite;

    JSONArray jsonarray = null;
    ListView list;
    TextView itemText,itemCount,rs,totalAmount,cartEmpty;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemlist;
    ArrayList<Product> tempMenu = new ArrayList<>();
    static String Array = "AllMenu";
    static String NAME = "name";
    static String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    static String PRICE = "price";
    static String IMAGE = "image_path";
    static String ORDER = "order";
    int count=0;
    int totalCartItemCount =0;
    int totalCartValue = 0;
    Button checkout_main;


    String url="http://mahatiffin.com/web/selectallmenu.php";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_item_layout, container, false);
        itemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new ReadJSON().execute();
        list = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        checkout_main = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_all_main);
        tempMenu = new ArrayList<>();
        getCartData();

        totalCartItemCount = tempMenu.size();
        totalCartValue =0;
        for (int temp1=0; temp1 < tempMenu.size(); temp1++)
        {
            totalCartValue = totalCartValue + Integer.parseInt(tempMenu.get(temp1).getFinalValue());
        }
        itemText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        itemCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_count);
        rs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalAmount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_amount);
        cartEmpty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cart_empty);

        if (totalCartItemCount == 0)
        {
            itemText.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            itemCount.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            rs.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            totalAmount.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            checkout_main.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            list.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            cartEmpty.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            itemText.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            itemCount.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            rs.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            totalAmount.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            checkout_main.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            list.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            cartEmpty.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
        }
        itemCount.setText("("+ totalCartItemCount + ")");

        checkout_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ExtrasItem.class));
            }
        });
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), itemlist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);
        return view;
    }
   public void getCartData()
    {
        Product tempCartItem = new Product();

        tempMenu.clear();
        sqLite=context.openOrCreateDatabase("mahatiffin",context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor c=sqLite.rawQuery("SELECT  FINAL_VALUE FROM CART",null);
        count=0;
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                tempCartItem = new Product();
                tempCartItem.setFinalValue(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FINAL_VALUE")));
                tempMenu.add(tempCartItem);
                count++;
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
        sqLite.close();
    }

    class ReadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

            Product tempMenu;

            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);
                jsonarray = jsonobject.optJSONArray(Array);
                //productList = json.getJSONArray("AllMenu");

                //parse date for dateList
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    tempMenu = new Product();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    tempMenu.setName(jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    tempMenu.setDescription(jsonobject.getString("Description"));
                    tempMenu.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("price"));
                    tempMenu.setImagePath(jsonobject.getString("image_path"));
                    itemlist.add(tempMenu);
                    //return ("OK");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And my ListViewAdapter is here..

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    // Declare Variables
    //Product tempMenu;
    Context activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ExtraMenu = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> AllMenu = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemlist) {
        this.activity=activity;
        AllMenu = itemlist;

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return AllMenu.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        Product tempMenu = (Product) AllMenu.get(position);
        TextView name, Description, price;
        ImageView image_path;
        ImageButton order;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_item_list, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_all_main);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_all_main);
        Description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_all_main);
        image_path = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_all_main);
        order = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.order); 

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        name.setText(tempMenu.getName());
        price.setText(tempMenu.getPrice());
        Description.setText(tempMenu.getDescription());
        order.setOnClickListener(new MyPersonalClickListener("order",tempMenu, (FragmentActivity) activity));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(tempMenu.getImagePath(),image_path);

        return view;
    }
    public class MyPersonalClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        String button_name;
        Product name;
        int tempQty;
        int tempValue;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLite;
        Context context;

        //constructor method
        public MyPersonalClickListener(String button_name, Product name, Context context)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.button_name = button_name;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            // in this section, we are going to add items to cart
            //if the item is already there in cart, then increase the quantity by 1, else add the item to cart
            //if the quantity of the item has reached 10, then do nothing ---this is just a specific logic where
            //i did not want any item with quantity more than 10, but if you choose not to, then just comment out
            //the code.
            sqLite=context.openOrCreateDatabase("mahatiffin", context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sqLite.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TB_MENU (ID INTEGER primary key autoincrement,NAME VARCHAR, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR, PRICE INTEGER)");
            sqLite.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CART (ID INTEGER primary key autoincrement, NAME VARCHAR, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR, PRICE INTEGER, MENU_QTY INTEGER, FINAL_VALUE INTEGER)");

            Cursor cc = sqLite.rawQuery("SELECT MENU_QTY, FINAL_VALUE FROM CART WHERE NAME = '"+name.getName()+ "'", null);

            if (cc.getCount()== 0)
            {
                //product not already there in cart..add to cart
                sqLite.execSQL("INSERT INTO CART (NAME,DESCRIPTION,PRICE,MENU_QTY,FINAL_VALUE) VALUES('"+name.getName()+ "','"+name.getDescription()+ "',"+ Integer.parseInt(name.getPrice())+",1,"+ Integer.parseInt(name.getPrice())+")");
                Toast.makeText(context,"Item "+name.getName()+" added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {

                //product already there in cart
                if(cc.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do{
                        tempQty=cc.getInt(0);
                        tempValue = cc.getInt(1);
                    }while(cc.moveToNext());
                }
                if (tempQty < 10)
                {
                    sqLite.execSQL("UPDATE CART SET MENU_QTY = "+ (tempQty+1)+",FINAL_VALUE = "+ (Integer.parseInt(name.getPrice())+tempValue) +" WHERE NAME ="+ name.getName());
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Item "+name.getName()+" added to Cart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            sqLite.close();

        }
    }
}
```

Error is here in coding

```
In listviewadapter error is here while i m adding one item second time my logcat says error in this line

    sqLite.execSQL("UPDATE CART SET MENU_QTY = "+ (tempQty+1)+",FINAL_VALUE = "+ (Integer.parseInt(name.getPrice())+tempValue) +" WHERE NAME ="+ name.getName());

In my All_Item_Fragment when i M ADDING item to cart my cart will display empty cart At this line error its shows getCartData(); in oncreateview(); and in getCartData(){sqLite=context.openOrCreateDatabase("mahatiffin",context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); }
```

Comment: what error does it show ?

Comment: 05-26 13:49:49.354 14654-14654/com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin.All_Item_Fragment.getCartData(All_Item_Fragment.java:114) at com.androidbelieve.MahaTiffin.All_Item_Fragment.onCreateView(All_Item_Fragment.java:59)at anddroid.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: sadcasc (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE CART SET MENU_QTY = 2,FINAL_VALUE = 556 WHERE NAME =sadcasc                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method) at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882) at com.androidbelieve.ListViewAdapter$MyPersonalClickListener.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:130)

Comment: what does sadcasc mean. is it only a string for condiational update

Comment: try to reinstall the app or clear app data from setting . may be its your database change.

Comment: sadcasc is one of my item name i m inserting it two times then it will shows  that error n app is dead

Comment: try to pull out your db using device monitor and test these query in sqlite tools(in  firefox extention add this tool ) and browse your db file which you pulled and test these query . thats all i can help

Comment: how i can do it i really dont know what u r saying i m new in android how i can do it.:(

Comment: check this to pull your db from app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio and this extenstion on firefox to open your db https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ and open your db using this tool you can see all your table and test query. what you are trying to do in app.

Comment: Okay sir i will try it now and gives u reply