# Can't unfold 'data' folder in Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

I want retrieve database from Android Device Monitor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio), but this time can not enter into /data folder. Why? Do you know any workaround?

Deleted, reinstalled app, restarted Android Studio etc.

[image]

Comment: Because you don't have root permission.

Comment: Do you know easy way to get 'root' permission?

Comment: you have to root your device to get root permission. You can check the method I suggested.

Comment: "I want retrieve database from Android Device Monitor as described here" -- those instructions are for emulators. Follow the other answers on that question for copying a database using `adb`, as that approach can work on devices as well. And, you will not have the security issues of your presently-accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of access you can create your database in mobile phone sd card or external storage also. By this way you can easily access database file.

You can do it like this

```
    public DatabaseHelper(final Context context) {
     //super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1); //for default location
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + FILE_DIR
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

Comment: This may offer "ease of access". It also is very insecure, as any app can now access this database.

Comment: @CommonsWare But this for testing purpose, after your app is ready you can put it back to default location.