# Datagrid in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, datagrid

are there any datagrids in android studio for handling database tables or do you have to create your own?

A bit like the one you have in visual studio [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View contents of database file in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: Ehm that one is about `ddms` not datagrid

Comment: Well, your question is rather vague.  You specifically asked about viewing data from a database table from within your IDE (i.e. Android Studio vs. Visual Studio)  Based on your own answer, I assume you're asking about whether Android supports viewing data in a grid layout - which it does, but that has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: i asked for a widget that could presents tabular view of data from the database tabel etc. datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is. It is called GridView: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: iknow but you cannot have the column and rows the same way as you can on a datagrid as gridview it will only be listet as item1 subitem1 item 2 subitem 2
and you also gona miss ascending descending