# How to access the SQLite database file in Android Virtual Device?

Tags: database, android-sqlite

I found the emulator is online in Android Device Monitor.
But the **data** folder seems to be empty and could not find any database file in it.

Since I could retrieve the data inside the database to the U I, I'm sure that the SQLite database is created.

- So how can I get the database file resides in the emulator?

I'm working on Android Studio 2.2.3 and using the API 23(Marshmallow).
I had referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio) link ,but couldn't find the right answer

Answer (score 0):

1. First check whether you've created any database for project or not. Obviously you don't see any db file if you don't have a DB module in your app. User SQLiteOpenHelper or ContentProvider to create a SB for your project.
2. Once you create a DB in your project, extracting db file should be simple. Use FileManager in DDMS or Android Device manager and manually go to your project data folder and pull file into your computer.

This should help.

Comment: I had already created a Databasehelper class extends from SqliteOpenHelper.But the data folder is seem to void in DDMS.Is there a way to check whether my database is created?

Comment: Please share the code. I can tell you what's wrong in it

Comment: I could display the details from database to my activity  and it works fine.So it is confirmed that the database had created.The problem is, I couldn't find the actual database file in Android Device Monitor