# Viewing database file of my android application in Redmi phones

Tags: android, redmi-device

My android application is not working in REDMI phones. Infact not sure because sometimes it stores the data and sometimes not. It gives unexpected results, i can able to access my application in other phones correctly.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280430/7505436

Answer (score 0):

use facebook stetho which allowed to access app database and fire query on it.
http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#integrations

once integration completed.check in google chrome browser : chrome://inspect/#devices

Answer (score 0):

First of all, see you logcat if nothing suspicious found then For debugging your database query take a look at this awesome open source library called Android Debug database
https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

This library operate through your browser and also give access to your app's shared preferences