# Insert value repeatedly (duplicate) shown when button click

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am Beginner of the android learner, I have one doubt, Saving Event from Calendar view, when I was submit my event, why after submission my inserted data repeated, Here is my code, I attached my screenshot output, give me sample and idea. Is it wrong to call the function in button, how can access it, Give solution for it.

[image]

```
btnEventSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String getEvents = edtEvent.getText().toString();
                    if (getEvents.length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter any events", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Event Submitted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        databasesqliteclass.createTabel();
                        databasesqliteclass.initialFunctionalities("insert into "
                                + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Constants.Column_1 + "," + Constants.Column_2 + "," + Constants.Column_3 + ","+Constants.Column_4+
                                ")values('" + getEvents + "','" + month + "','" + dayOfMonth + "'" + ",'" + year + "'"+ ")");
                        databasesqliteclass.selectQuery("Select *from " + Constants.TABLE_NAME);
                        databasesqliteclass.printTableData();
                        ArrayList<String> dataList = databasesqliteclass.printTableData1();
                        Log.i("dataList", "" + dataList);
                        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
                            Log.i("getsplit", "" + dataList.get(i));
                            String splitfrst = dataList.get(i);
                            String getsplitans[] = splitfrst.split("-");
                            String geteventss = null;
                            String geteventdate = null;
                            String geteventmonth = null;
                            String geteventyear=null;
                            Log.i("getsplitansgetsplitans", "" + getsplitans);
                            for (int j = 0; j < getsplitans.length; j++) {
                                geteventss = getsplitans[1];
                                geteventmonth = getsplitans[2];
                                geteventdate = getsplitans[3];
                                geteventyear=getsplitans[4];
                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(geteventmonth);
                                SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
                                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
                                String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
                                Log.i("month_name", "" + month_name);
                                Log.i("getevents", "" + geteventss);
                                Log.i("geteventmonth", "" + geteventmonth);
                                Log.i("geteventdate", "" + geteventdate);
                                eventsmodel = new Eventsmodel();
                                eventsmodel.setStrrevents(geteventss);
                                eventsmodel.setStrDate(geteventdate);
                                eventsmodel.setStrMonth(month_name);
                                eventsmodel.setStryear(geteventyear);
                            }
                            mCatagoryList.add(eventsmodel);
                        }


                        EventAdapter eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mCatagoryList);
                        Eventlist.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Here is my select query,i called it in button click for saving the values into database

```
public ArrayList<String> printTableData1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME, null);
    if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            data = new ArrayList<String>();
            do {
                row_values = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    row_values = row_values + "-" + cur.getString(i);
                }
                Log.d("LOG_TAG_HERE", row_values);
                data.add(row_values);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it's inserting multiple time? or is it showing multiple times? the way you are doing sqlite, is not a good approach

Comment: showing multiple times,then how to access the sqlite

Comment: To access sqlite - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and use your `Eventsmodel` outside the for loop. See below code.

```
for (int j = 0; j < getsplitans.length; j++) {
    geteventss = getsplitans[1];
    geteventmonth = getsplitans[2];
    geteventdate = getsplitans[3];
    geteventyear=getsplitans[4];
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(geteventmonth);
    SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);
    String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
}

eventsmodel = new Eventsmodel();
eventsmodel.setStrrevents(geteventss);
eventsmodel.setStrDate(geteventdate);
eventsmodel.setStrMonth(month_name);
eventsmodel.setStryear(geteventyear);
```