# Android realtime database inspection

Tags: android, greendao, android-jetpack, sqlite-browser

I am working on an app and using GreenDao for database. So now to debug and inspect and validate database changes I have to do fetch out the database file after making any changes to database.

To get the database file I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio) way. But truly speaking it is very much pain for me to perform a minor change and to check it I have repeat several number of steps again and again.

I have seen that in iOS I have used Realm Database and I used their Realm Browser and that was very easy to use, as that browser showed me changes in real time from simulator.

> **Now my question is, in Android Did not we have such tool to get
>   changes in real time in Database browser**.

I am using SQLite Browser please help and let me know if you know some tools.

Comment: You can try Stetho. See https://android.jlelse.eu/android-browsing-realm-database-on-windows-3d2b4fc3de92 for reference

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with `Room` with the `paging library`. Using a **MVVM architecture it can be achieved** !

The there will be an `observer` in the activity which will observe the dynamic data changes of the repository. *When any data change occurs the `observer` is triggered and it updates the UI with the new data* .

Go through [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) & [PagingWithViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/data)

The configuration of the data from repository and the conversion of it to livedata is important.

```
 val myPagingConfig = Config(
    pageSize = 50,
    prefetchDistance = 150,
    enablePlaceholders = true
 )

 // The Int type argument corresponds to a PositionalDataSource object.
 val myDataSource : DataSource.Factory<Int, Pojo> =
    myDao.getData()

 val dataList = myDataSource.toLiveData(
    pagingConfig = myPagingConfig,
    fetchExecutor = myExecutor
 )
```

Comment: but I am using Greendao and now I can not change it