# Android Studio Save and view data in database on Android Device

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I created a database using android studio and view it through `sqlite` db. But in order to view my database i need to pull out from device file explorer. How can I save and view my database in actual device without pulling out from device file explorer, my android studio version is 3.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View contents of database file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: I think ```Stetho``` library can help you. https://github.com/facebook/stetho

Comment: Though there are some applications you can download and view the data stored in the database, it is best to use Stetho library. For more details you can check this [link](https://medium.com/quick-mobile/stetho-a-debugging-bridge-for-android-applications-eacc139dfda7)

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps :

> Device File Explorer > data > data > yourPackageName > databases > filename.db

**After that :**
1) Select the file.
2) Right click on it.
3) Choose save as and give it proper name and destination.

**Note : You can only view the database file of your own application. And application debuggable mode is on.**