# Can any body able to see offline sqlite db data from apk using android studio in flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, offline, sqflite

I want to create an flutter app that will work offline. I have stored data in an SQLite database using SQLite plugin. Is it possible to access SQLite db data offline, from an APK using Flutter in Android Studio?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio).

Answer (score -1):

if you initialize it with some tables or rows yes ofcourse using [DB Sqlite Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: Okay.so someone could steal data from apk easily?Thanks for responding.

Comment: no, there will be os level constraints, it is hard to read Whatsapp database on the devices and that tells me that os level constraints apply to every app

Comment: Data fetched from sqlite is visible in emulator.But when i install the apk in my mobile, its displaying blank?