# How can I view the contents of my AVD database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I've already followed the instructions in the top answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio).

Using the device file explorer in Android Studio, I find my app's database. I then right click on the "databases" folder and click save as. I save it in a development folder elsewhere. [image: Device File Explorer] [image: File Path]

I have downloaded both DB Browser for SQLite and Sqliteman. Both of these programs cannot open the files from above.

When I "Open Database" in DB Browser for SQLite, it does not see the files in my file path. [image: DB Browser finds no files.]

When I open the files in Sqliteman, I get an error. This is true for all three files. [image: Sqliteman Error]

In my app, some fields in the database are working. When I try to display the data (in my app) the date and time stamps show up, but the text does not. I was hoping that I could look at the tables in my database to see if they're even being saved.

I'd love to see the tables in my database. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Download also the -shm and -wal files.

Comment: I downloaded all three files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Here's what I did:

All three files just needed to be renamed to .db, .db-shm, and .db-wal respectively. DB Browser was able to open the files. Sqliteman still won't work. It's probably too old.