# Insert users information inside database java on android studio

Tags: android-studio

Good evening to all,
I am creating an application with java on android studio.but after creating my database and making the registration page, the information does not go into the database.the errors I had said that there is a colons not created, I checked and everything is in place. when I remove the code that allows the insertion of information in the database the application works if not it is blocked at the stage of registration.I also tried nothing

A part of my database code

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Login.db";
    public static final String TABLE_SIGN = "userss";
    //public static final String TABLE_PROSPECT = "prospect";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String ID_COL= "id";
    public static final String NAME_COL = "name";
    public static final String USERNAME_COL = "username";
    public static final String EMAIL_COL = "email";
    public static final String PHONE_COL = "phone";
    public static final String PASSWORD_COL = "password";

 


    public MyDbHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_SIGN
                + "(" + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL ,"+
                NAME_COL + "TEXT,"+ USERNAME_COL + "TEXT," + EMAIL_COL + "TEXT," + PHONE_COL
                + " TEXT,"+ PASSWORD_COL + "TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SIGN);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String username, String email, String phone, String password)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(NAME_COL, name);
        contentValues.put(USERNAME_COL,username);
        contentValues.put(EMAIL_COL,email);
        contentValues.put(PHONE_COL,phone);
        contentValues.put(PASSWORD_COL,password);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_SIGN, null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

The registration methods





btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nam = name.getText().toString();
                String user = username.getText().toString();
                String email = mail.getText().toString();
                String phoneN = phoneNo.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();

                if(nam.equals("") &&  user.equals("") && email.equals("") &&  phoneN.equals("") && pass.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Veuillez remplir tout les champs",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    Boolean regResult = db.insertData(nam,user,email,phoneN,pass);
                    if(regResult == true)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Connexion réussie avec succès",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LogIn.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Echec de connexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The errors that i have:

```
  2021-06-23 22:51:16.489 28861-28861/com.example.suiviprospection E/SQLiteLog: (1) table userss has no column named email
    2021-06-23 22:51:16.490 28861-28861/com.example.suiviprospection E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting phone=60005882 email=shiv@gmail.com name=GOGNON Shiva password=Shiv username=shiv
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table userss has no column named email (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO userss(phone,email,name,password,username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
            at com.example.suiviprospection.MyDbHandler.insertData(MyDbHandler.java:76)
            at com.example.suiviprospection.SignUp$1.onClick(SignUp.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thank you for helping me , I'm waiting for your answers

Comment: Hi, are you able to see the column in the [table inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: Hi,no I use API 25 but to inspect my database I need API 26

Comment: Log the SQL statement created in the `onCreate`. You will probably see it contains  something like `nameTEXT,usernameTEXT,emailTEXT` Tbh, I'm quite surprised, it has even created a table ...

Comment: Excuse me but i don't understand correctly. Should i add onCreate(db); ?

Comment: The query you use in `onCreate` of the database is wrong. So it will create a wrong table (if creates any table at all). Fix that query (ie add the missing whitespaces between the column name and the type of the column) and then try to recreate your database ...

Comment: Hello ,
Indeed it was the problem, I noticed it while configuring the database inspector yesterday. The spaces between the name of each column and the type of each column.
Thanks a lot for your help.